# Bootstrap radio buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, radio-button

I have 3 different sets of radio buttons on the same page. The problem I am experiencing with them is that when a button in another btn-group is pressed it will toggle the state of the buttons in the previous or next btn-group.  They don't seem to be independent.  Here's the code:

```
 <div id="file1" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="yes">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="radio"  name="radioGroup2"onClick="$('#mandatory1').val('no');">No</button>
</div>

 <div id="file2" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="yes">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="radio"  name="radioGroup" onClick="$('#mandatory2').val('no');">No</button>
</div>
```

When a button within div file1 is clicked it toggles the state of a button in div id file2

I've tried using button.js with this, but no luck.
I've tried various different variations of data-toggle="button"

Any ideas?

Comment: Well spotted. But still it hasn't fixed the problem. I've updated the code above.

Comment: It's actually the whole HTML you've created for bootstrap radios that's wrong.

Comment: post a fiddle of the problem. comparing to boostrap's documentation you have not used the same layout at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should fix your problem:

```
<div id="file1" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" value="yes">Yes</label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2" onclick="$('#mandatory1').val('no');">No</label>
</div>

 <div id="file2" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="yes">Yes</label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger active"><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" onclick="$('#mandatory2').val('no');">No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I Always test before posting, but sometimes you can have another code that may crash with it

Answer (score 5):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edLq5/1/)

Your HTML structure for bootstrap radio buttons is wrong.

```
<div id="file1" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" >
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="option1" /> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger">
        <input type="radio" name="option1" /> No
    </label>
</div>


<div id="file2" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" >
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="option2" /> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger">
        <input type="radio" name="option2" /> No
    </label>  
</div>
```

**Aside:**

You're using jQuery; Please don't use `onClick` in your HTML. You would set up those events like this (though there is a way that involves less code).

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.btn').button(); // this is for the radio buttons.

    // this replaces your inline JS
    $('#file1 .btn-danger').on('click', function(){
        $('#mandatory1').val('no');
    });
    $('#file2 .btn-danger').on('click', function(){
        $('#mandatory2').val('no');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edLq5/3/)